# PHP - Get absolute path of a php script for a url working in local and in remote

Tags: php

I have a php script that contains login and logout links that i want to use in my whole website.
The intention is to have a variable that contains the URL that can be used through the entire site and never changes with the current page location

Using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` i get:

> localhost/~MyName/MySite/current_folder

and it changes depending on the current location

Using `__DIR__` i get:

> /Users/MyName/Sites/MySite/php

Where "php" is the folder that contains the script

What i'm searching is:

> localhost/~MyName/MySite/php

Where i'm in local, and:

> https://www mysite com/php

Where i'm on the internet

I want the path to be stored in a variable and used in the script:

```
<?php
   echo ("<a href= '$path . /logout.php'> Logout </a>");
?>
```

Comment: you want the path or the url? Two different animals. And what's wrong with the first attempt?

Comment: i need a string to put in <a href=$mystring . "/logout.php">Logout</a> The first attempt gives me the current dir not the dir of my php folder

Comment: and the php folder is what? The doc root? Or is localhost your doc root?

Comment: I think you should just set the virtual host to `localhost/~MyName/MySite/` and go with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/php"`

Comment: the php folder is in my root (root/php) and contains the script

Comment: if it was the root, then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would not include `~MyName/MySite/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place in your webroot index.php file at the top

```
define('URL', filter_var(rtrim('http'.(((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])), '/').'/', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

in an MVC setup, this will allow `URL` to always equal your web root.

Comment: Note that `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is based on user-supplied data so can't always be trusted. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is subject to XSS attacks, though in this context the risk is limited.

Comment: The $_SESSION method that you give me works for me.. However if someone accesses my site from another page all links doesn't work.